# OPC UA Read string[] data type by nodes with path

Tags: java, c#, client, opc, opc-ua

This is a example.

```
Node Path = "Tool/Manager/Name"
```

`Node data Type = "string"` and data is `"Jone"`

When I use `nodesToRead.Add(new NodeId(path, 6));` Is work!

But, if I change the node data to `string[]{"Jone","Peter","Himari"}`

When I use `nodesToRead.Add(new NodeId(path, 6))`, It return a `System.string[]`. and I need to use some methods to get string[0] data.

How can I read the "Jone" by only node path without do some methods to get "Jone"?

---

This is used Softing(Software) to read my server. It read an array type. {AA,NN,CC}

I want to know how to read each elements by set Browse Name?

Example: only read "AA" by set Browse Name?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4usLR.png)

Because the Siemens OPC Server can read read each elements by set Browse Name.

It's Browse Name can set like AxisNameList[u1,1] to read the array{1},and It Configuration Browse only one node like "AxisNameList" Node.

if i publish this path "AxisNameList", it will by request array[0] data.

if i publish this path "AxisNameList[u1,1]", it will by request array[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4usLR.png)] data.

If i want to achieve this function, How do i modify my OPC UA Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPC UA Specification Part4

5.10.2 Read Service
Parameters of Read Service is defined as following

[Read Service Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbzf2.png)

The type of nodesToRead[] is ReadValueId,
which is defined as following

[ReadValueId DataType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb6rM.png)

indexRange is the parameter you need.

So, OPC UA supports reading a single element of an array.
But i don't known if your SDK support it.

here is the datatype of readparameters in the sdk i used.

```
struct ReadParameters 
{
     double MaxAge;
     OpcUa::TimestampsToReturn TimestampsToReturn;
     std::vector<OpcUa::ReadValueId> AttributesToRead;

     ReadParameters();
};
struct ReadValueId 
{
     OpcUa::NodeId NodeId;
     OpcUa::AttributeId AttributeId;
     std::string IndexRange;
     OpcUa::QualifiedName DataEncoding;
};
```

Comment: I went to use node path to get array data without use some methods.

Comment: Because when I use siemens CNC machine tools. It can read as like /Channel/MachineAxis/measPos2[u1,1] to read position.

Comment: but when I see it node List. It just Node path as /Channel/MachineAxis/measPos2

Comment: and i use like this path "Tool/Manager/Name[0]", and it show BadNodeIdUnknown.

Comment: My OPC UA SDK is C# version.

Comment: your application is opc ua client, right? when you want to read data from server, you may have to call a function in sdk, like "Read". look into parameters you passed to the function